# C++ to port member function from other classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Suppose I have two different classes shown below

```
class Nonlinear
{
   public:
   double NonlinearFunc(ParameterList) //it is a nonlinear function 
};

class Solver
{
   public:
   double FuncEvaluation(ParameterList) //evaluate a function
};

double Solver::FuncEvaluation(ParameterList)
{
    ????? //evaluate function from other class
}

main()
{
    Nonlinear nl;
    Solver solve;
    double a;
    double b;
    a = nl.NonlinearFunc(ParameterList);
    b = solve.FuncEvaluation(ParameterList);

    //what I want is a=b
}
```

How do I use member function pointer so the Solver::FunEvaluation evaluates Nonlinear::NonlinearFunc?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you have a specific instance of `Nonlinear` class, which methods you want to call? Or `NonlinearFunc` is in fact `static`? Why do you think you need member function pointer?

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with C++, I have modified the code so as to make more clear what I want.

Comment: @kz965: Which `Nonlinear` object should have it's `NonlinearFunc` member called by `Solver::FuncEvaluation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `Solver::FuncEvaluation()` to execute `Nonlinear::NonlinearFunc()`, is that correct?  If so, I would do it like this:

```
class Evaluatable
{
public:
   virtual double Evaluate(ParameterList) = 0;
};


class Nonlinear : public Evaluatable
{
public:
   double Evaluate(ParameterList);
};

class Solver
{
public:
   double FuncEvaluation(Evaluatable &expression, ParameterList);
};

double Solver::FuncEvaluation(Evaluatable &expression, ParameterList params)
{
    return expression.Evaluate(params);
}

main()
{
    Nonlinear nl;
    Solver solve;
    double a;
    a = solve.FuncEvaluation(nl, ParameterList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to evaluate the function, you don't actually need to use the pointer to member, you can just make an outright call:

```
class Solver
{
 public:
   Solver(Nonlinear& nl) : mNl(nl) {}
   double FuncEvaluation(ParameterList) //evaluate a function
 private:
   Nonlinear& mNl;
}; 

Solver::FuncEvaluation(ParameterList l)
{
  return mNl.NonLinearFunc(l);
}
```

Otherwise you'd have to use pointer to the member function AND still pass object instance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `NonLinear::NonLinearFunc()` from `Solver::FuncEvaluation`.

As your class `Solver` is not derived from class `NonLinear`, and as `NonLinearFunc()` is a member function of class `NonLinear`, you must have in `FuncEvaluation` an object (let's call it `x`) of class  `NonLinear`, for example, one of the parameters.

If this is the case, you don't need a pointer to a member function, but just call the function:

```
 x.NonLinearFunc(...)   // or x->NonLinearFunc(...) if you work with pointers.
```

A pointer to a member function would then only make sense, if you would have several similar member functions and would like to dynamically choose one.

**Edit:**

For using a pointer to a member function, when really necessary, do as follow:

```
double (NonLinear::*f)(...); // declare a pointer to a member function of Nonlinear
f = &A::NonLinearFunc;       // Assign the address of the function to the pointer.  Note the mandatory &    
(x.*f)(...);                 // call the function pointed to, using NonLinear object x with the given parameters
```

Note that in this example, the pointer `f`  is not a member of `NonLinear`, but a variable with type "pointer to a member function of class `NonLinear`".  It would be a variable of your solver.

Comment: How do I use a pointer in Class Solver to point to a member function in Class Nonlinear if I would like to dynamically choose a member function in Nonlinear? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you want the function `FuncEvaluation` to be able to accept *any* (member) function as a parameter and evaluate it using its own parameters.

In modern C++ you can do something like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
struct Solver {
    template <typename Callable, typename... Args>
    auto funcEvaluation(Callable&& c, Args&&... args) {
        return std::forward<Callable>(c)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

And use it for example like this:

```
struct NonLinear {
    /* Some member function */
    double nonLinearFunc(double x, double y, int m) {
        return (x + y) * m; // (Not non-linear but serving as a simple example.)
    }
};

int main() {
    Solver s;
    NonLinear nl;

    // Use standard library call wrapper for member functions.
    auto c = std::mem_fn(&NonLinear::nonLinearFunc);

    // When using call wrapper you need to pass instance 'nl' as parameter.
    std::cout << s.funcEvaluation(c, nl, 1.0, 2.0, 2) << std::endl;

    // Outputs 6.0
}
```

<kbd>[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59c8b167a0e239a8)</kbd>

<sub>1: You will need C++1y support for function return type deduction to work.</sub>